# Convert GeoJson to latLng coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, kml

I'm trying to change a path color, based on it's coordinates. I need to change the color for every segment of the path, so I think I need to convert the coordinates to an array and then apply a style for each segment.

So far I managed to read KML file, apply it to the map and change it's color (with [LeafletJs](https://leafletjs.com/) and [Omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore)):

```
// declaration of the map container
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([latitude, longitude], zoomValue);

/ declaration of the map layer
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=TOKEN_VALUE', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

// read and parse the KML file containing the path to be colored
var runLayer = omnivore.kml("kml/path.kml")
    .on('ready', function() {
        runLayer.eachLayer(function (layer)
        {   
            layer.setStyle({
                color: '#f44336',
                weight: 4 
            });
            
        }).addTo(mymap);})
```

However this change the color to the entire path, I need to know how to analyze and change each single segment color based on it's specific coordinates.
I've tried getting an array of coordinates `coordsToLatLngs` but there is no documentation on how to use it and I cannot make it work.
I've tried

```
var coords = L.coordsToLatLngs(runLayer.coordinates);
```

but it gives me the error

```
L.coordsToLatLngs is not a function
```

so I tried

```
var coords = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(runLayer.coordinates);
```

and

```
var coords = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(runLayer.coordinates, 0, false);
```

but now they both return

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Comment: One problem I think you're facing is that omnivore creates a Leaflet layer as part of its process which means you can't touch the geoJson in between. You may have to do the KML -> geoJson conversion yourself, modify the geoJson from one feature layer (which is what you have currently) to an _array_ of feature layers (one layer per set of coordinates which would allow you to style them separately), and then apply that feature collection to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution:

```
var runLayer = omnivore.kml("kml/path.kml")
.on('ready', function() {
    runLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        
        // convert GeoJson coordinates to array
        var coordsArr = layer._latlngs;

        // for each segment
        var i = 0;
        while (i + 1 < coordsArr.length) {
            
            // get the start and end coordinates for the line
            var lineStartPoint = L.latLng(coordsArr[i]);
            var lineEndPoint = L.latLng(coordsArr[i + 1]);
            var lnPts = [lineStartPoint, lineEndPoint];
            
            // the color to be changed
            var clr = '#0b5394';
            
            // logic for color change here
            
            // insert a polyline with the coordinates and color retrieved before
            var polyline = L.polyline(lnPts, {color: clr}).addTo(mymap);
            
            // counter increment
            i++;
        }
    });
})
```